# ‘Function?’ can’t be assigned to the parameter type ‘void Function()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to assigned to the parameter of type Function

**this context not work in the declaration of my parameter.**

`final Function onChanged;`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**i used that now :**

`final void Function(bool)? onChanged;`
`final void Function(double)? onChanged;`
`final void Function(String)? onChanged;`